# Welche Bedeutung hat "Borussia" im Namen von Sportvereinen?

Tags: etymology, single-word-request, history

Eine ganze Reihe von deutschen [Sportvereinen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borussia) trägt die Bezeichnung "Borussia" ([lateinisch für Preussen](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Borussia)) in ihrem Vereinsnamen.

Für [Borussia Dortmund](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borussia_Dortmund) lese ich bei Wikipedia zur Namensgebung:

> Einer Anekdote zufolge wurde der Zusatz „Borussia“ gewählt, weil es sich um den Namen des im Wildschütz ausgeschenkten Bieres der Borussia-Brauerei handelte, die unweit des Borsigplatzes ihren Sitz hatte.

War dies aber wirklich der Grund zur Namensgebung, und warum heißen dann so viele andere Vereine ebenfalls "Borussia"? Was soll mit diesem Namenszusatz ausgedrückt werden? Gibt es einen direkten Bezug zum Sport?

Comment: Es gibt „preußische Vereine”, z. B. [Preußen Münster](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preußen_Münster). Und analog: Bayern München, Erzgebirge Aue, Westfalia Herne, … (Bevor mir Interesse an Fußball unterstellt: Ich bin einfach eine ewige Liste der Zweitliga-Vereine durchgegangen.)

Comment: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSC_Preussen

Comment: Ha also doch! Ihr seid gut :=) dann muss ich meine Frage anpassen ;)

Comment: Was ist eigentlich dann mit Dynamo Dresden? Das macht ungefähr genausoviel Sinn..

Comment: Lokomotive Leipzig ist bestimmt auch eine interessante Geschichte

Comment: Für Dynamo und Lokomotive sollte man hier schauen: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sportvereinigung#Liste_der_Sportvereinigungen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ich habe auf Wikipedia Folgendes gefunden:

> ### **Borussia, Preußen**
>
> Ein besonders häufiges Beispiel für einen Regionalbegriff im Vereinsnamen. Das Wort Borussia stammt aus dem Lateinischen und bedeutet Preußen. Oft deuten diese Namen darauf hin, dass die Vereine von preußischen Soldaten oder Polizisten gegründet wurden. Bei Borussia Dortmund ist dies jedoch auf den Namen einer Brauerei (Borussia-Bier) zurückzuführen, vgl. dazu auch Borussia Dortmund. Im DFB gibt es ca. 60 Vereine mit dem Namen „Borussia“ sowie 38 Vereine mit dem Namen Preußen.
>   Bekannte Träger: *Borussia Dortmund, Borussia Mönchengladbach, Tennis Borussia Berlin, Borussia Fulda, Preußen Münster, BFC Preussen*."

Answer (score 0):

Der Stamm war nicht baltisch sondern slavisch und die "Germanen oder Katholiken" haben dessen Territorium annektiert. Dieses Völkchen hieß "Porussen" und nicht Prussen oder Pruzzen (Fehlerhaft bei Wikipedia).
*PO* bedeutet hier *entlang*, *auf* oder *zusamen* und *RUSSEN* bedarf keiner Übersetzung.

Hier noch weitere Beispiele:
 - *Pomeranie* - Am Meer entlang
 - *Polesje" - ein Stück Wald oder grosser Wald
 - *Powolzhje* - das Gebiet entlang der Wolga 
usw.

Also ist *Borussia* transformiert von Porussia. Tut mir sehr leid wenn ich dich(euch) jetzt enttäuscht habe.
Übrigens: das Wort Dolmetscher ist auch von russischen "TOLMATSCH" :TOL(k)-Sinn,  matsch - tun,machen.

Comment: Willkommen auf German Language SO. Bitte nimm Dir einen Moment Zeit und blättere durch die [Tour] und das [Help] .
Ich habe mir erlaubt, Deine Antwort zu editieren, um sie etwas lesbarer zu machen. Solltest Du mit den Änderungen nicht einverstanden sein, kannst Du selbst ebenfalls ändern.

Comment: @Dmitrij Wikipedia erlaubt sich, die dort wiedergegebenen Behauptungen mit Quellen zu untermauern. Solche fehlen bei dir. Ich würde dir empfehlen, Quellen, die deine These untermauern, zu verlinken, denn ohne solche kann sie schnell für eine [Volksetymologie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volksetymologie) gehalten werden.

Answer (score -1):

Borussen stammt von Prussen, einem im Mittelater ausgerotteten baltischen Stamm, deren Name vermutlich  "bo+russ= Rinder+rot" d.h. "die mit den roten Rindern" bedeutete.

Comment: Bitte um eine Referenz für diese (gewagte) These zur Etymologie.

Comment: Den Stamm hat es wohl gegeben, aber mit 'rot' scheint der Name nichts zu tun zu haben: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pru%C3%9Fen

Answer (score -1):

Das Wort Borussia hat bis 1518 nicht exsistiert, es wurde von dem Fälscher und verurteilem Betrüger von geschichtlichen Ereignissen  Johanntes Stüler alias Erasmuus Stelle fabriziert in seinem Buch der Geschichte von Preußen Seite 10 und 11.

Comment: Die angebliche "Fälschung" scheint nicht bewiesen zu sein. Eine andere Aussprache in regionalen Dialekten und somit eine im 16. Jhdt. nicht unübliche divergente Schreibweise wäre zumindest denkbar. Immerhin meinte "Borussia" auch damals "Preußen". Ob das nun eine richtige oder eine falsche Schreibweise war, wird man wohl heute kaum klären können. Hast Du eine gute Referenz, die du hier zitieren könntest?

Comment: Selbst *wenn* das Wort 1518 ein "Fake" war - Sollen wir es dann 500 Jahre später deshalb abschaffen? Wir haben im Deutschen viele Worte, die erst weit nach 1518 aufgekommen sind. Von daher sehe ich die Relevanz der Antwort nicht.

Comment: Natürlich haben Sie Recht das Wort Borussia kann man im deutschen nicht abschaffen, das ist auch nicht meine Absicht, doch dass Preußen aus Borussia entstanden ist, ist ein Fake und das soll man abschaffen. Wenn C. Ptolomäos schreibt Borusker und J.Stüler daraus Borussia macht, ist das ein Fake. Wenn J.Stüler aus dem SK in Borusker ein SS macht, ist das eine grobe Fälschung. Es gäbe ein Disaster, wenn man diese Art von Änderung auf alle anderen Sprachen dieser Welt anwenden müsste, wie viele Worte mit SK gibt es in dieser Welt?